# Draw little circle/flag next to text in table cell (not aligned right)

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with lots of cells in it. Some of these cells should be flagged as warning, others as alert.

I have come up with the following HTML/CSS to do something like this.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.circle {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ff0000;
    float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1 cellpadding=0 style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td width=150 height=30>hello
                <div class='circle'>I</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Which displays the text like...

[image]

However, I want it to display with the little flag immediately to the right of the text, like this...

[image]

If I change the CSS to specify `float: left;` this then displays the flag before the text.

The reason I want it aligned to the right of the text, is that depending on the width of the column, it might not be obvious which text is being flagged.

ps. I've included the td width/height just so that I can demonstrate what I'm trying to do, there's also no table borders in my final design.

Comment: Just remove float, and make sure it's `display: inline`  or use a span instead of a div

Comment: I had tried display: inline, and also using a span, but the circle appears very narrow, i.e. 3 or 4 pixels wide

Comment: Following @Phiter's idea, use `display: inline-block;` and you should be set.

Comment: yes, inline-block did it. thanks. Feel free to add this as an answer, and I'll accept it. thanks

Comment: Doh! I was typing it up as your guys discussed. just missed it. Best of luck!

Comment: Yeah I forgot that `inline` elements can't have `width` and `height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid making your circle narrow by using `display:inline-block;` and remove the float all together.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.circle {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ff0000;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1 cellpadding=0 style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td width=150 height=30>hello
                <div class='circle'>I</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make Couple of adjustments to your code:

Change:

```
hello
```

To:

```
<div style="float:left;">hello</div>
```

And In CSS

Change:

```
float:right;
```

To

```
float: left;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.circle {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ff0000;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1 cellpadding=0 style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td width=150 height=30><div style="float:left;">hello</div>
                <div class='circle'>I</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting alternative to the other answer, I guess both will work equally well. I've tried both and they align slightly differently, but both good.

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between a `<div>` and a `<span>` is how they affect the layout.

A `<div>`, by default, is a block element and wants to live on its own line.

A `<span>`, by default, is a inline element and will sit next to the element before and after it.

Changing to a `<span>` and getting rid of the float will solve the problem. Though you do need to set its `display` value to something like `inline-block` to allow the `width` and `height` values to work correctly.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.circle {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1 cellpadding=0 style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td width=150 height=30>hello
                <span class='circle'>I</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```